# Connection to different SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I want to create a connection to a SQL Server Database using a python script that you will see below. In fact, I managed to connect to a single database but I want to make a loop on a database list so that every time I point to a database I can connect directly. 
My question is how can I make the name of the database as a variable. Could you help me please?! Thank you in advance

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

mypath = 'C:\\Users\\DataBaseList'


onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for i in range (len(onlyfiles)) : 
  print (onlyfiles[i]) 


connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};"
                  "Server=FR0010APP31;"
                 "Database= Base;"
                 "uid=*****;pwd=*****")

cursor = connection.cursor()
sql='Select * from Activity'
df= pd.read_sql(sql, connection)
df.to_csv('DatabaseFile')
```

Comment: Don't make the name a variable. Run a `USE someDB;` SQL statement to switch to a different database each time

Comment: Another option is to use a three-part name, ie `database.schema.table`, eg `myBase.dbo.Activity`. You'll have to replace the database name in the query each time though. Databases can't be parameters any more than tables can. They are similar to types in a program. A query itself isn't executable. The database (any database) parses that query and creates an execution plan based on the table schemas, indexes, and data statistics. Query parameters are actually parameters for the execution plan. Change the table or database and everything else changes too

Comment: Thank you for your answers!